# jQuery selector containing variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

If I use a selector with a variable, I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

I read lots of threads on this, but I haven't found an answer yet.
The input is loop per lesson, so this is an upload form for every every lesson.
If I place an `id`, I don't get the error, but since I loop through the form, jQuery doesn't read the id and the code crashes.

```
$('.addmaterial_div').each(function(i, div) {

    $(div).find('input').each(function(j, element) {
        if (bid == $(this).attr('id')) {
            fs = $(this).attr('id');

            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', $('#' + fs)[0].files[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'uploadmaterial.php',
                encType: "multipart/form-data",
                data: fd,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log('upload success!')

                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I guess it's because `$('#'+fs)[0].files` is undefined. Have you debugged your code?

Comment: how to check if its undefined? im new to this

Comment: Here's a documentation page that explains debugging: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/642/debugging#t=201705071249426142422

Comment: i;ve checked it and on my page its empty,,